# Twitter user timeline in ListView by Fabric

Tags: android, listview, twitter, twitter-fabric

It's possible to get a user timeline inside of a `ListView` using fabric and the Twitter SDK because its exactly what I need for my App (I like the formatting and its simple).

Here is my testing code. I get tweets inside the `ListView` by tweet ID.

```
package com.example.elfassimounir.happh;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.CompactTweetView;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.LoadCallback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetUtils;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetViewFetchAdapter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


// Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "xxxxxxxx";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxx";

List<Long> tweetIds = Arrays.asList(503435417459249153L,
        510908133917487104L,
        473514864153870337L,
        477788140900347904L,
        510908133917487104L,
        473514864153870337L);
final TweetViewFetchAdapter adapter =
        new TweetViewFetchAdapter<CompactTweetView>(
                MainActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);

    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.tweet_list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setTweetIds(tweetIds,
            new LoadCallback<List<Tweet>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<Tweet> tweets) {
                    // my custom actions
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    // Toast.makeText(...).show();
                }
            });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have an answer for my question thanks to twitter fabric team.

This code is searching for the user i need his tweets:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {



// Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "XXXXX";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "XXXXX";

private boolean flagLoading;
private boolean endOfSearchResults;
private static final String SEARCH_QUERY = "NFL";
private TweetViewAdapter adapter;
private static final String SEARCH_RESULT_TYPE = "recent";
private static final int SEARCH_COUNT = 20;
private long maxId;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tweet_list);

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetUi(), new Twitter(authConfig), new TweetUi());

    setUpViews();

    loadTweets();
}

private void setUpViews() {
   // setUpBack();
    setUpPopularList();
}

private void setUpPopularList() {
    adapter = new TweetViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.loading));
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {
            if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) &&
                    totalItemCount != 0) {
                Crashlytics.log("Bla bla..");
                if (!flagLoading && !endOfSearchResults) {
                    flagLoading = true;
                    loadTweets();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
private void loadTweets() {
    Crashlytics.log("Bla bla...");
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    final SearchService service = Twitter.getApiClient().getSearchService();
    service.tweets(SEARCH_QUERY, null, null, null, SEARCH_RESULT_TYPE, SEARCH_COUNT, null, null,
            maxId, true, new Callback<Search>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<Search> searchResult) {

                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    final List<Tweet> tweets = searchResult.data.tweets;
                    adapter.getTweets().addAll(tweets);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (tweets.size() > 0) {
                        maxId = tweets.get(tweets.size() - 1).id - 1;
                    } else {
                        endOfSearchResults = true;
                    }
                    flagLoading = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException error) {
                    Crashlytics.logException(error);

                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.toast_retrieve_tweets_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    flagLoading = false;
                }
            }
    );
}
```

this example is very helpful : [cannonball app](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android)

Comment: what to do to get only "user's feed" not "for user feed"(re-tweeted)...??

Comment: here we are just searching for the username.  to get what you need, there is "userTimeline"..

Comment: currentally using your code i am getting both tweeet 1> user's tweet 2> another tweet which is used my tweterid like @userid

Comment: or you can improve your search

Comment: but i want only option 1> so can u help me?

Comment: as i said by searching.. the results will be very inefficient since 99% of the data is filtered out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94199/discussion-between-dhruv-raval-and-mounir-elfassi).